# Issue printing leaflet map and imagery layer using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, leaflet, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

currently we are working on a web tool using Ruby on Rails and one of their functions is generate a PDF report based in HTML template, that template has a map built with leaflet-0.7.3 and we are using a gem called pdfkit v0.8.2, wkhtmltopdf-binary v0.9.9.3 to generate PDFs, but right now we are facing an issue with that report, when It generates that report it is splitting the map and layers like this:

[PDF error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noe5p.png)

It is supposed to look like this

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlYth.png)

Any suggestions what's going on? or what should we do?

Any help would be great for us! thank you guys

Comment: Looks like it could be down to styles not being applied. Are you passing it a stylesheet?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css

Comment: what does the code look like for this?

Comment: I have verified the code and HTML template doesn't have errors

Comment: Thank you DMH for you help, it was solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue with my HTML template when It was generated, so, I solved it replacing my leaflet stylesheet with the last version, which is

http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css

please, replace your current stylesheet and share me what was your result.

Comment: My map does not fully display. Even when wrapping into an iframe as suggested in https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1648, my content is shifted a bit... actually I am using wkhtmltopdf on the commandline :(